# Angular JS form model value changed to an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a fairly normal form in angular with a title, body field and also has a dropdown select with a list of options.  The options are hard coded, but the backend only accepts an array of objects while the body accepts on key with object.

My input currently looks as so:

```
<label for="platform">Platform</label>
<select id="platform" name="platform" class="form-control" ng-model="lfg.field_platform">
    <option value="1183">Option 1</option>
    <option value="1184">Option 2</option>
    <option value="1182">Option 3</option>
    <option value="1188">Option 4</option>
    <option value="1186">Option 5</option>
    <option value="1185">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

As expected this returns:

```
{
  "title": "test",
  "body": "here is the body",
  "field_platform": "1184"
}
```

However I need field_platform to return:

```
{
  "type": "dataset",
  "title": "Just a title",
  "body": {
    "value": "Detailed text goes here"
  },
  "field_platform": [
    {
      "id": 1184
    }
  ]
}
```

Can I properly format this using just the ng-model directive or will I have to do some more work in the controller to format body and field_platform?

Comment: I figured out the body field, but still not sure about the array of objects for my select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FKBKW6BrxXfob69hLLY2?p=preview) for both solutions

**Solution 1:**

If you are using angular v1.3 you can use [`ngModelOptions`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.18/docs/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) with `gettersetter` option set to true. Then restructure your model to have getters and setters:

```
  $scope.lfg = {
    field_platform1: null,
    fieldPlatformFn: function(value) {
      return arguments.length ? this.setFieldPlatForm(value): this.getFieldPlatForm();
    },
    getFieldPlatForm: function() {
      return this.field_platform1 && this.field_platform1.length > 0 && this.field_platform1[0].id;
    },
    setFieldPlatForm: function(value) {
      return this.field_platform1 = [{"id": parseInt(value)}];
    }
  };
```

and your select will have to reference the `gettersetter` function in `ng-model`

```
<select
    id="platform"
    name="platform"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="lfg.fieldPlatformFn"
    ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}">
```

**Solution 2:**

Create your own directive to formatter and make use of the `ngModelController` [parsers and formatters](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.18/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers)

```
app.directive('toArray', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return value && value.length > 0 && value[0].id;
      });

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return [{id: parseInt(value)}];
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

With markup:

```
  <select
    id="platform2"
    name="platform"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="lfg.field_platform2"
    to-array="">
```

Answer (score 0):

BigglesWorth

I believe the most proper way to do it would be having your array formatted, but it can be demanding. What you could do is to `$watch('model', function(){})` your model, and then do the magic trick. You might even have another variable for the purpose of getting the right formatted object, and avoiding nesting your object array.

Hope this will help you